# Convert a String to boolean

Tags: java, string, boolean

I need to solve this exercise using java code:

We have a monkey and a boolean parameter aSmile, we need to know if the monkey is smiling and if it is "We are in trobule" if it is not "We are good".

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class taxi {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean aSmile;


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Is monkey A smiling?");
    String answer = scan.nextLine();
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
         aSmile = true; 
    }
    else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
        aSmile = false;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, write a correct answer");
    }


    if(aSmile = true){
        System.out.println("We are in trouble");
    }

    else if (aSmile = false){
        System.out.println("We are good!");
    }
   }
}
```

The problem is that I always get "We are in trobule", no matter what I write in the console.

Comment: Change `if(aSmile = true){` to `if(aSmile){` **or** `if(aSmile == true){`; one `=` is *assignment*.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(aSmile = true){ //Look here.
    System.out.println("We are in trouble");
}
```

You are assigning the value `true`to the variable aSmile.

Replace it with :

```
if(aSmile) { //Or if(aSmile == true) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an assignment operator and then check for the boolean value.

```
if(aSmile = true){
        System.out.println("We are in trouble");
    }
```

`aSmile` will always be true, because you assign it `true` and then check if it's `true`. You have to use the `==` operator or in this case simply

```
if(aSmile){ // means if aSmile is true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly used conditional operator.
It should be like

```
    if(aSmile){

     }
```